# Prevent iPhone app to run on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, sdk

I'm shipping two binaries; one for iPhone/iTouch and the other for iPad.  It's the same application.

Will Apple ensure that the user will never receive an iPhone version of the app on the iPad? If YES, then I don't have anything to worry about, but if not then I do have a problem.

The reason I ask is the iPhone application will simply not work correctly on the iPad because the server knows it's an iPad and will deliver the iPad HD content to it and the iPhone cannot handle that.  I would rather not hack my application to send the server a fake device type if running the iPhone app on the iPad in order to receive the correct resources.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just make your app send the correct device type to the server? I thought that Apple didn't want platform specific apps (ie. they want any app to run on iPad and iPhone/Touch).

Comment: @Leifur, Your app will likely get rejected.  I can't find anything now, but Apple wants a single universal binary for apps now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way, since apps like Angy Birds have a dedicated 'HD' version for iPad.

Comment: Why ship two binaries when you could ship one that works on both devices?

Comment: @Joe - They are not nonsense.  What is being asked is if it is possible to prevent an iPad from running a particular application, not if it is possible to build an application that is targeted for the iPhone (but still runs on the iPad in compatibility mode).  Therefore, it is perfectly legitimate to point out that Apple will reject applications that do this and that the proper way to solve the problem would be to control the content delivery correctly at the server side.

Comment: Thank you guys for good answers.  The "correct" thing to do is to control the content delivery from the server, so the server knows if requests are coming from the iPhone or iPad application.  Reason why I'm not shipping an universal app is basically because the resources are different for iPhone than iPad and it is a waste of space to bundle iPad resources and controllers into the iPhone app.

Answer (score 17):

I've been looking for this for a while because I couldn't prevent the iPhone app to load on the iPad. Searched a bit to understand why this was happening, followed @hotpaw2 instructions and found this on the official apple store rules:

[image: Apple Store official rules excerpt - developer.apple.com]

#### UPDATE:

> 2.4.1 To ensure people get the most out of your app, iPhone apps should run on iPad whenever possible. We encourage you to consider
> building universal apps so customers can use them on all of their
> devices. Learn more about Universal apps.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: if this is the case, how is whatsapp doing it?

Comment: @AceNeerav looks like the guidelines have changed. "2.4.1 To ensure people get the most out of your app, iPhone apps should run on iPad whenever possible. We encourage you to consider building universal apps so customers can use them on all of their devices. Learn more about Universal apps."

Answer (score 10):

The SDK and/or App store rules prohibit you from preventing an iPhone app from running on an iPad in 1X or 2X zoom mode, unless there are other requirements listed in the app plist.  Apple's app review is known to test iPhone-only app submissions (unless there are other requirements) on an iPad, and reject the app if it doesn't run properly.

Other requirements (as listed under UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the app's plist) might include your app requiring telephone capabilities (or healthkit, etc.), which might help you temporarily, but still won't prevent the app from running on some hypothetical future iPad product that includes telephony capabilities (and/or healthkit, etc.).

Comment: Can you please provide any official information about this prohibition?

Comment: Look in the required Functionality section of the App Store Review Guidelines on developer.apple.com

Comment: I dont understand nothing from this answer. Please be more concise.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can. 
Add `telephony` to `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in your plist file.

But i really not recommend it and maybe you could get rejected because of gratuitously using this property.

I think you should handle that there are iPad versions and iPhone versions on iPads, use the second one as an iPhone.
Also don't forget that retina iPads will use upscaled applications at retina resolution while none retina ones use the standard resolution. And this behavior can tweaked using jailbreak tweaks like RetinaPad and FullForce.

Answer (score -5):

In the plist settings, add `Application requires iPhone environment` and set the boolean to `YES`

Comment: This does not prevent an iPhone app from running on an iPad

Comment: Wrong. Even an iPad-only application has this same flag set to YES, thus this does not restrict an iOS app from running on an iPad.