# Prevent an iPhone app from running on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, info.plist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent iPhone app to run on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186746/prevent-iphone-app-to-run-on-ipad)

Is it possible to prevent my iPhone app from running on an iPad, not even the X2 version.

Thanks

Comment: The Big question is "Why woukd you want to do that?". Hopefully Not in order to push a separate version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Article about how [Prevent iPhone app to run on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186746/prevent-iphone-app-to-run-on-ipad)

Comment: @Idan hope you are not wanting to force "stop" the user from running the app on the iPad, because this is a no-no as per the App Store guide lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use **UIDevice**'s `model` method to get device name in string.

```
NSString* deviceType= [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

**Possible** examples of model strings are **@”iPhone”** and **@”iPod touch”.**

So you could get the model name in the starting of the application and  could show the appropriate  popup for showing like "Currently No supporting the iPad" and exit from the application.

Comment: You sure that won't get my app rejected ? cause from other answers it seems it would.

Answer (score -2):

In the plist settings, add `Application requires iPhone environment` and set the boolean to `YES`